# Background-color with floating elements

Tags: css, html, css-float, background-color

I have a problem while I want put 2 vertical `DIV` inside a main `DIV`. The `background-color` value does not work for the main `DIV`. I think I have to see some sections with red background color.
Please take a look at its [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vKUS2/3/) and help me to solve it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with adding a empty div with `clear:both` CSS attribute or set a height to your main div.

```
<div id="content">
    <div id="float-left">Some Text floating left</div>
    <div id="float-right">Some Text floating right</div>
    <div id="clear"></div>
</div>
```

CSS Code

```
#content {
    background-color:red; /* The background you want */
    width:500px; /* Demo: not important */
}

#float-right {
    float:right;
    width:300px;
    padding-right:20px;
    line-height:200%;
    background-color:#f2f2f2
}

#float-left {
    float:left;
    width:50px;
    background-color:#e1e1e1
}

#clear{
   clear:both
}
```

[See Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/96res/)

Answer (score 0):

It's because your parent DIV has no height. You set the child DIVs to float so it won't affect the size of the parent DIV. You will need to manually set a height for the parent DIV or use the clear:both; attribute

Comment: You will need to add a new DIV inside the parent DIV (after the 2 child ones) and define clear:both; in the style attribute for the new DIV